# AudioStreamer works on iPhone (Device) but crash on simulator

Tags: ios, audiostreamer

```
if (!streamer) {
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://y1.eoews.com/assets/ringtones/2012/5/18/34049/oiuxsvnbtxks7a0tg6xpdo66exdhi8h0bplp7twp.mp3"];
    AudioStreamer *tempStreamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self.streamer = tempStreamer;
    [tempStreamer release];
}
 [streamer start];
```

When it begin to play, it crash in simulator and xcode shows the erro is :libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw, but it runs well in device.in another demo, it runs well both in simulator and device.

I can not find the reason.

Comment: Thanks bro....
You save my repetition

Comment: After three days long research i got right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have enabled beakpoint for *All exceptions*, please disable it from Breakpoint Navigator. This should solve your problem.